# Reattaching water meter

Tags: plumbing

I'm trying to reinstall the water meter pictured below. It it has plastic male threads on each side, and they connect to the copper piping using a flare fitting (I think that's the right terminology).

[image]

[image]

I can't get the connections not to leak, even if I really crank down with my pipe wrench.

Possibly relevant is that there are rubber gaskets that appear to go into each fitting, as pictured below. I used the gaskets and it still leaks, but perhaps the gaskets are just shot (they appear worn).

[image]

Any ideas on why I can't get the connections to work?

Comment: That type of connection is *not* called a flare. I would call them flat sealing surfaces, or union type sealing surfaces, but I don't know the exact terminology They have to be nearly perfectly aligned and if they are not I think the connection will leak. If you get new seals and the connections still leak, then I'd say alignment is off. Are any of the surfaces scored or otherwise not smooth?

Comment: Also, fittings that have rubber seals _usually_ do not have to be super tight because the rubber does a lot of the sealing work.  In other words, making the fitting too tight will strip the threads and it just shouldn't need that much force.

Comment: One of the washers in the photo looks like it has a significant amount of debris stuck to it (sand or dust?). Have you inspected the mating surfaces of the meter and the pipe, and also both sides of the gaskets, to ensure that each is clean, smooth, and free of nicks or scratches?

Answer (score 1):

I would first ask why you removed the water meter. they are usually sealed with a type of non removable link that has to be cut to remove so the customer can not move the meter and steal water. Usually, if there is a leak at the meter you should contact the water company and they will fix the problem.. That said, if this water meter is the one supplied by the local water company, you could call them and ask if they could provide you with the correct type gaskets (leather). If they ask why the meter was removed find a credible answer that you think they will accept. I rarely saw rubber type washers used on a water meter.

Comment: It's a foreclosure and the water meter was removed previously (don't know why). But I believe this is also just an internal meter for the homeowner's use, and the municipality has another meter somewhere that they read for billing. Anyway, it sounds like alignment could be the issue, so I'll work from there.

Comment: One thing you want to do is try to get each side started and not tighten either side until they are both started. Wiggle the meter if need be to get the threads started. Once started tighten each side evenly until tight. If it's that far out of alignment and if it is a customer only meter then bypassing it may be a better option than trying to align it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the water meter police and think it is your business why the meter is being replaced. That said, I would replace the rubber washers and do not tighten too much. It's hard to describe because you want to tighten it with a wrench, but not as tight as you can get it. I also agree that alignment is key on this type on joint. If the two pieces aren't perfectly in-line with each other and you have to pull/push one of them to get it in-line, it has a good chance of leaking.